Seaborn Lineplot: Further Breakdown After Hue
I want to further break down this code by another column in the df named 'chamber'. This current version results in two lines, Dem and Rep, but the desired result should be 4 lines; House Dem, House Rep, Senate Dem, and Senate Rep. Does anyone know how I can do this?
    sns.lineplot(x='year',
    y='age',
    hue='party',
    data = dem_rep,
    )

I've spent 20 minutes searching for an answer  but couldn't find one

sns.lineplot(..., style='chamber')?
